# TypeError: Cannot read property '_attributes' of undefined after update

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

**TypeError: Cannot read property '_attributes' of undefined**

After I rebuild my sails app to **sails@0.10-rc6** and **sails-mysql@0.10-rc5**.

Logs :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_attributes' of undefined
    at /Users/tebesfinwo/Sites/club_script/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/adapter/sync/strategies/alter.js:83:68
    at bound (/Users/tebesfinwo/Sites/club_script/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:957:21)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/Users/tebesfinwo/Sites/club_script/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:365:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/Users/tebesfinwo/Sites/club_script/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:264:18)
    at _normalizeCallback.callback.success (/Users/tebesfinwo/Sites/club_script/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/node-switchback/lib/normalize.js:33:26)
    at _switch (/Users/tebesfinwo/Sites/club_script/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/node-switchback/lib/factory.js:34:26)
    at /Users/tebesfinwo/Sites/club_script/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:116:16
    at Object.module.exports.poolfully [as releaseConnection] (/Users/tebesfinwo/Sites/club_script/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/release.js:28:12)
    at /Users/tebesfinwo/Sites/club_script/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:101:35
    at Query._callback (/Users/tebesfinwo/Sites/club_script/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:438:11)
```

Note :

**sails@0.10-rc6** & **waterline@0.10-rc11** : throw the error above.

Comment: What version of waterline are you using? What adapter are you using?

Comment: waterline@0.10.0-rc11

Comment: Adapter?...also when does the error occur?

Comment: It happened when I lifted the app. So I try to revert back sails@0.10-rc6, which has waterline@0.10.0-rc9. However, another problem arises, the model object is not able to be populated.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this question, looks like he's using sails-mysql

Comment: Are you able to connect to your database? Does all the data look right, check that first.

Comment: Also are you able to post the model code?

Comment: Yes, I have posted my model and the function above. Yes, I am able to connect to database with **sails@0.10-rc6** and **waterline@0.10-rc9**, not with **waterline@0.10-rc11**.

Comment: @InternalFX You know what. I have discovered my mistake. There's no records associated with the model, therefore it couldn't be populated. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue introduced into a particular version of [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) (rc11).  It's recommended that you upgrade to the v0.10.0-rc7 release of Sails, which will fix this and some other issues.  That's:

```
npm install sails@beta
```

or

```
npm install -g sails@beta
```

for a global install!